# Identity on Gauss' Theorem involving Laplacian and Div

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $V$ be as in Gauss' Theorem, and $f, g \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3; \mathbb{R})$. Prove that

$$\int_{\partial{V}}f\ \nabla g \cdot \mathbf{n}\ dS = \int_V(f\ \Delta g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g)\ dV.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, in general,

$\nabla \cdot (f\nabla g) = f  \nabla^2 g + \nabla f  \cdot \nabla g, \tag{1}$

a well-known identity from vector calculus; see for example http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence.  If we integrate (1) over a region "V . . . as in Gauss' theorem" we obtain

$\int_V \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g) dV = \int_V(f \nabla^2 g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g) dV, \tag{2}$

and now we can in fact *use* Gauss's theorem on the left-hand side to obtain

$\int_{\partial V} (f \nabla g) \cdot \mathbf n dS = \int_V \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g) dV = \int_V(f \nabla^2 g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g) dV, \tag{3}$

proved as per request.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Green's first identity, I think. Its proof can be found quite easily around.